# Is the function $\sqrt x$ onto in its domain?

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, functions

The domain of $\sqrt x $ is $0\le x<\infty$

And its co-domain is $0\le y<\infty$

We know that the square root function is one-to-one since there exist only a unique $y$ such that $y^2=x$ since $y^2$ is a strictly increasing function.
That is, $ z>y \implies z^2>y^2$.

But my question is whether the function $y=\sqrt x$ is surjective (onto) or not. Please explain it.
Thanks.

Comment: I do not understand what is being asked.  Could you elaborate on what you mean by "whether the function is onto its domain or not (cis)?"

Comment: Well, the domain is $[0, \infty)$. Can you show that for all $y \in [0, \infty)$ you can find some $x$ such that $y= \sqrt{x}$?

Comment: The notion of ‘onto’ involves the codomain, not the domain. Simply, it happens, in the present case, that the range, not the codomain, is also the domain.

Comment: Is sqrt function is surjective?

Comment: This depends what you consider the codomain: if it's $\mathbf R$, it's not onto.

Comment: What is your codomain?

Comment: Co-domain is set of non negative real number.

Comment: Your question talked about range but not codomain.

Comment: Unless otherwise mentioned, a real function has codomain $\mathbf R$. More generally, if $f\colon X\to Y$ is any mapping, $X$ is the domain (or source) and $Y$ is the codomain (or target).

Comment: I edited the question to reflect the OP's intent. Y'all need to remember that not all board participants are native English speakers.

Comment: But it is not about "English".

Comment: If we consider range as co domain,can give a proof that sqrt function is onto?

Comment: Basically, for onto function, you have to show that range = codomain. If you consider codomain is $[0,\infty)$, then the proof goes as follows in @mathguy 's answer.

Comment: "Codomain" shouldn't be what one "considers it to be"; a function is a relation between two sets, the domain and the codomain. A function is not even well-defined if the domain and the codomain are not explicitly determined. Before talking about a function at all (even regardless of any questions of surjectivity) the codomain must be known.

Comment: I guess we (me and @Bernard ) are trying to say the same thing.

Comment: @Rajat: I quite agree with you. From the beginning, I have felt some ambiguity about these notions in the O.P.'s mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $f:[0,+\infty)\to [0,+\infty), \;\;f(x) = \sqrt x$ to be onto its domain (or "surjective"), you must prove that for every $y \in [0, +\infty)$ (the co-domain of $f$) there is at least one $x \in [0,+\infty)$ (the domain of $f$) so that $f(x) = y$. And indeed, such an $x$ exists, namely $x = y^2$.

Comment: But in the question, codomain is not mentioned.

Comment: The codomain (or target) of $f$ is not the range in general. The domain is the source of $f$.

Comment: In general, codomain and range are different. For onto map, you have to prove indeed both are same.

Comment: OK, I guess I forgot the English terminology. I will correct my answer.